# Combine two or more table into one object

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, methods, static-methods

I need to combine two or more table into one object by using C# 4,0... I wrote a class for a table which included simple select selectbyid insert update and update.... it works fine for single table... by the way I have two attribute which specifies table name column name and primarykey... by using all these I can create my simple methods but I need to select and update more table in one object or method... what should I do or what would you suggest about it... 
Example:

users and customer table I have foreign keys which defined...

Answer (score 0):

If you`re using linq to sql, you can join the other tables like

```
 var q = 
   from s in db.Suppliers
   join c in db.Customers on s.City equals c.City
   select new {
      Supplier = s.CompanyName,
      Customer = c.CompanyName,
      City = c.City
   };
```

as just copy & paste from a sample of MSDN [LINQ to SQL: .NET Language-Integrated Query for Relational Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx#linqtosql_topic12)

Comment: Thank you mark ,but im not using linq i made my own domain object class, im using my own methods and attributes and im trying to create my own method , i just need an idea or example :D